# Curve objects flickering in animation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, bezier-curves

I have an animation in which several curve objects are being used as animated callouts for a product render. There are 36 blends and only 10 of them have rendered properly. The other 26 have certain frames where the curve objects just disappear in the render. It's only for one frame at a time, some renders it's only a couple frames and others it's so many frames it creates a lot of flickering. I have not been able to figure out a solution. I have rendered in different versions of Blender, copied all the objects from the scene into a blank blend file, but neither of these fix it. The only thing that has worked, with a caveat, is turning off the product mesh and only rendering the callouts. This of course comes with the issue of having to composite the two together which I was hoping to avoid.

I have looked high and low for information on what might cause potential flickering on curve objects, but I have had no luck.